# How to preserve values of fields on jsp page when jsp is calling servlet and redirecting back to same jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a one welcome.jsp page where I am collecting few information and with the help of HTML FORM sending this request and response object to servlet to insert data into DB, so after this operation I want to go back to the same Welcome.jsp, but when I tried to use the 
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
rs.forward(request, response);

I lost all the populated values on the same Welcome.jsp, 
So please suggest is there a way where I can send the existing request and response object with new request and response to the servlet and will send back old request and response object from servlet to JSP.

So below is code from "Welcome.jsp"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="***********"%>
<%@page import="java.io.Console"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Treatment Dashboard</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<!--   <script type="text/javascript">
        function noBack()
         {
             window.history.forward()
         }
        noBack();
        window.onload = noBack;
        window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
        window.onunload = function() { void (0) }
    </script> -->    
</head>

<body>
    <%
        HttpSession sessions = request.getSession();
        String lanId = (String)sessions.getAttribute("lanid");
        System.out.println("session Lanid:- " + lanId);
    %>
   <!-- Codrops top bar -->
   <div class="codrops-top">

                <a>
                    <strong> VALUES </strong>
                </a>

                <span class="right">

                        <strong> VALUE </strong>

                </span>                        
  <div class="menu-area">
    <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
      <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
      <ul class="dl-menu">
        <li><a href="#intro">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#WeekendsShift">Weekends Shift</a></li>
        <li><a href="#compoff">Comp Off</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LogoutServlet">Log Off</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- intro area -->
  <div id="intro">

    <div class="intro-text">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="intro-data">
            <div class="brand">
              <%            
                  String fname      = (String) request.getAttribute("fname");
                  String lname      = (String) request.getAttribute("lname");
                  String emailid    = (String) request.getAttribute("emailid");
                  String ext        = (String) request.getAttribute("ext");
                  String rmlanid    = (String) request.getAttribute("rmlanid");
                  String role       = (String) request.getAttribute("role");
                  String ipadd      = (String) request.getAttribute("ipadd");
                  String wcounts    = (String) request.getAttribute("weekendsCount");
                  String acocounts  = (String) request.getAttribute("appliedCompOff");
                  String rcocounts  = (String) request.getAttribute("remainingCompOff");
                  String pacocounts = (String) request.getAttribute("appliedCompOffPendingApprovalcount");   
              %>              
               <table style="width:100%" >
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userName" class="uname" data-icon="u"> Name :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userName" class="uname" data-icon="u"><%=fname%> <%=lname%></label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userEmail" class="email" data-icon="u"> Email :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userEmail" class="email" data-icon="u"><%=emailid%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userExt" class="ext" data-icon="u"> EXT :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userExt" class="ext" data-icon="u"><%=ext%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userRmlanid" class="rmlanid" data-icon="u"> RM Lan-Id :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userRmlanid" class="rmlanid" data-icon="u"><%=rmlanid%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userIpadd" class="ipadd" data-icon="u"> TechM Machine IP :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userIpadd" class="ipadd" data-icon="u"><%=ipadd%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userWeekendsNumber" class="weekends" data-icon="WND"> Worked ON Weekends :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userWeekendsNumber" class="weekends" data-icon="WND"> <%=wcounts%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                   
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userCompOffApplied" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> Applied Comp Off :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userCompOffApplied" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> <%=acocounts%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="userCompOffAvailed" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> Remaining Comp Off :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userCompOffAvailed" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> <%=rcocounts%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td>
                            <label for="userCompOffPendingApproval" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> CompOff Pending For Approval :- </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>            
                             <label for="userCompOffPendingApproval" class="compoff" data-icon="u"> <%=pacocounts%> </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                                       
                      <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="submit" value="Update"/>          
                             <!-- <input type="submit" value="Cancel"/> -->
                        </td>
                      </tr>                                                                               
                </table> 
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<!-- Weekend Shift -->
  <section id="WeekendsShift" class="home-section bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="intro-data">
            <form  method = "post" action="AddWeekendsShiftDetails" autocomplete="on" >             
               <div class="brand">    
               <table style="width:100%" >                  
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> <br><br><br>
                                <label for="weekendDetails" class=""> Worked On Weekend :- </label>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><br><br><br>
                                <input type="text" id= "datepicker1" placeholder="Weekend Date" name="pickedDate"/>
                                <script>
                                    var datepicker = $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                        changeMonth: true, 
                                        changeYear: true                                      
                                        }).val();                               
                                </script>
                            </p>                            
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                     <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p> <br>
                                    <label for="processname" class="uname" data-icon="PN" > Process Name :- </label>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p> <br>
                                    <input id="processname" name="processname" required="required" type="text" placeholder="ex:-BAC"/>                                    
                                </p>
                            </td>
                      </tr>                                                               
                      <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>
                            <p> <br> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;          
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                             </p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                                                                               
                </table> 
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Comp Off -->
  <section id="compoff" class="home-section bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="intro-data">
            <form  method = "post" action="AddCompOffDetails" autocomplete="on" >
                <div class="brand">
              <%  
                final String USER_WEEKENDS_COMPOFF_DETAILS_QRY = "SELECT WEEKEND_DATE FROM tbl_weekend_rota WHERE (LANID= ? and IS_COMPOFF_CONSUMED = 'N' and IS_APPROVED != 'P')";
                Connection con = null;                  
                con = DBConnection.createConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ps =con.prepareStatement(USER_WEEKENDS_COMPOFF_DETAILS_QRY);
                ps.setString(1, lanId);

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
              %>              
               <table style="width:100%" >      
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> <br><br><br>
                                <label for="userName" class=""> Apply CompOff :- </label>
                            </p>    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><br><br><br>
                                <select name="compOffDate">
                                    <option>-- Available CompOffs --</option>
                                    <%  while(rs.next()) { %>
                                        <option><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                                    <% } %>
                                    <% con.close();%>
                                </select>
                            <p>                             
                        </td>
                      </tr>                                                                   
                      <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Apply"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;         
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/> 
                                <br><br>
                             </p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                                                                               
                </table> 
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

But when I clicked on **Submit** button it calls the **AddWeekendsShiftDetails** servlet, 
So in this case this form will send its own request and response object right ?
So from the **AddWeekendsShiftDetails** servlet  I'm inserting values to the Mysql DB

Below is the code from **AddWeekendsShiftDetails** servlet:-

```
package com.taskManagment.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Date;

//import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AddWeekendsShiftDetails")
public class AddWeekendsShiftDetails extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public AddWeekendsShiftDetails() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
        String sDate = request.getParameter("pickedDate");
        String processName = request.getParameter("processname");       

        try {                       
            Date sqlDate=Date.valueOf(sDate);

            Connection con = null;
            con = DBConnection.createConnection();

            String lanId = SessionDetails.getDetailsFromSession(request, "lanid");
            System.out.println("session Lanid from Weekend Servlet:- " + lanId);

            insertWeekendShiftDetails(con, lanId, processName, sqlDate);
            con.close();

            /*RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
            rs.forward(request, response);*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void insertWeekendShiftDetails(Connection con, String lanId, String processname, Date date ) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            String insertWeekendRotaDetails = "MY INSERT QUERY";

            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

            ps = con.prepareStatement(insertWeekendRotaDetails);
            ps.setString(1, null);                  ps.setString(2, lanId);
            ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) date);    ps.setString(4, processname);           
            ps.setString(5, "Y");                   ps.setString(6, "N");           
            ps.setString(7, null);                  ps.setDate(8, null);
            ps.setString(9, "N");                   ps.setDate(10, sqlDate);
            ps.setDate(11, null);

            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now from the **doPost** when I want to go back to the "Welcome.jsp" with the code like

```
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
rs.forward(request, response);
```

so it will send back the request and response object of the form which was called from the  section
and because of which the other values on the fields are getting null,
So I want a way with which I can hold the old values on **Welcome.jsp** page.

Comment: You can use sessions for this. Post your code so we can see

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the reply, added more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

before sending it back you need to set the attributes you want to the request. You can do that using request.setAttribute("attribute_name","attribute_value"); and the you can retrieve it by using request.getAttribute in the next page. For example

```
request.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Invalid data . Please correct the input data");
requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

And then in error.jsp you can use:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("errorMsg") %>
```